# Irreducible $\mathbb{F}G$ -module

Tags: representation-theory

There are two independent questions.

Q1: 
       $G$ is a finite group. $\mathbb{F}$ is a field such that Char$\mathbb{F} \nmid |G|$. Let $V$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{F} G$-submodule of $\mathbb{F} G$.  $\Phi : V \rightarrow W$ is an $\mathbb{F} G$-isomorphism, where $W$ is an $\mathbb{F} G$-module.
Then there exists $w$ in $W$ sucht that $\Phi (v)=vw$ all $v$ in $V$.

Q2:
      $G$ is a group. Let $W$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{F} G$-module and $A$ be the annihilator of $W$. 
Give a chracterization of $A$ in terms of irreducible $\mathbb{F} G$-submodules of $\mathbb{F} G$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi. One should ask independent questions indenpendently. And can you show some of your work?

Comment: All I know is for each $w$ in $W$ , $\Phi_{w} :v \rightarrow vw $ is an $\mathbb{F}G$-homomorphism.
If there is a $w$ such that $\Phi_{w}$ is isomorphism,
we can consider the map   $ f: vw \rightarrow \Phi(v)$, that  is, composition of $\Phi$ and inverse of $\Phi_{w} $. And then we have $\Phi = \Phi_{w} f$. The result is from the equality of maps.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** Hint 1: Show that any homomorphism $V\to W$ extends to a homomorphism $\mathbb{F}G\to W$.
Hint 2: A homomorphism $\mathbb{F}G\to W$ is determined by the image of which element?

**Q2:** This is not unrelated to **Q1**. Compare the definition of $\operatorname{ker}(\Phi)$ to the definition of $A$.